# How to check three conditions in succession?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruqpL.png) This is what my database looks like
,

if the first ad block is loaded -> stop checking and execute it -> if the first one is not loaded -> check the second one -> the second one is loaded -> stop checking -> the second one is not loaded -> check the third one .

Tried to execute through Switch case. Only the first block is executed. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

```js
//Variable for changing ads
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reklama");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    // Creating an ad targeting object.
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    int Reklama = Math.toIntExact((Long) snapshot.getValue());
     if (Reklama == 1) {
                int hi = 1;
                switch (hi) {
                    case 1:
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                        break;
                }
                if (hi != 1) {
                    int mid = 2;
                    switch (mid) {
                        case 2:
                            mInterstitialAdMid.loadAd(adRequest);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (mid != 2 || hi != 1) {
                        int low = 3;
                        switch (low) {
                            case 3:
                                mInterstitialAdLow.loadAd(adRequest);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (Reklama == 2) {
                int hi = 1;
                switch (hi) {
                    case 1:
                        mRewardedAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                        break;
                }
                if (hi != 1) {
                    int mid = 2;
                    switch (mid) {
                        case 2:
                            mRewardedAdMid.loadAd(adRequest);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (mid != 2 || hi != 1) {
                        int low = 3;
                        switch (low) {
                            case 3:
                                mRewardedAdLow.loadAd(adRequest);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello you need some cleanup here. Is this the real code? Pozdrav iz Srbije.

Comment: Please read how to use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: This looks like Java?

Comment: Andy , Java language is used

Answer (score 0):

If your case is sequential like 1,2,3. Rather than writing a switch case, you can do the following.

- Let's say that your value is 2

  const val = 2;
- Create a loop like below

  ```
  for(let i=1;i<4;i++){
   if(val === 0) break;
   if(i === val) {
     // if ad is found then execute the ad and stop the loop.
     // ex - if val is 1 then ad 2 and 3 wont be processed.
     loadAd(params);
     break;
   }
  }
  ```

With this approach, you are not restricted to the number of switch cases you can add. If in the future you need to check for 5 ads then you just need to increase the number in the loop.

Also, this will check the ads in a sequential manner. Will start with 1 and end with whatever number you provide.

Please find the implementation below.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reklama");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  // Creating an ad targeting object.
  final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  int Reklama = Math.toIntExact((Long) snapshot.getValue());
  for(let i=1;i<4;i++){
     if(Reklama === 0) break;
     if(i === Reklama) {
       // if ad is found then execute the ad and stop the loop.
       // ex - if val is 1 then ad 2 and 3 won't be processed.
       mInterstitialAdMid.loadAd(adRequest);
       break;
     }
   }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
});
```